# NOT LIKE in MYSQL INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have inner join two table and data in columns is array ids:

```
table : blocks have unload_category_id = ',12,19,'
table : videos have category_id = ',1,4,12,n,...,'
```

I want When query all data in videos table but no query videos have category 12 and 19 or n of id

```
WHERE ... AND videos.category_id NOT LIKE ('%,12,%','%,19,%')
```

return error.

help me fix NOT LIKE condition. thankyou!

Comment: Most times it's not a good idea to store character separated lists of values in just one single column. It's asking for trouble like this. You've got to use ` category_id NOT LIKE '%,12,%' AND category_id NOT LIKE ...`

Comment: thankyou. i resolve error. i use more values. it working.

Comment: Did you work with using multiple ` category_id NOT LIKE..`? If yes then - when you will have to check for 10 or more values, it won't be good to have such a long query. @Ratan's `REGEXP` looks good here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your array ids into table (that what it's for), and you would be able to use the full power of SQL (like subqueries).

Now for your problem, there is syntax error:

```
WHERE ... AND videos.category_id NOT LIKE ('%,12,%','%,19,%')
```

Should be:

```
WHERE ... AND ( videos.category_id NOT LIKE '%,12,%' OR videos.category_id NOT LIKE '%,19,%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try doing this...

```
WHERE ... AND videos.category_id NOT REGEXP '(^|,)(12|19|n)(,|$)';
```